# Arrowhead CSS…add arrowheads to the end of these lines?

Tags: html, css

How can I add an arrowhead to the end of each line where it meets the viewport's edge/pointing towards the viewports edge, ie., top, right, bottom, left? I'd like the arrowheads to be about 3 rem (~50 px) and that the line acts as the shaft of the arrow. I'd like the arrow head to not be filled, i.e., drawn with lines that nave the same props as the current lines (1 px solid deeppink). Here's a mockup:

[image: mockup]

Here's my current code:

```css
        body {
            margin: 0;
            padding: 0;
        }

        .horver {
            width: 100vw;
            height: 100vh;
            display: grid;
            place-content: center;
            position: relative;
        }

        .horver::before {
            content: "";
            position: absolute;
            top: 50%;
            left: 0;
            width: 100%;
            height: 1px;
            background: deeppink;
            background-image: linear-gradient(to right, transparent 49%, deeppink 49%, deeppink 51%, transparent 51%);
            background-size: 100% 1px;
            background-position: center;
        }

        .horver::after {
            content: "";
            position: absolute;
            top: 0;
            left: 50%;
            width: 1px;
            height: 100%;
            background: #ff1493;
            background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom, transparent 49%, deeppink 49%, deeppink 51%, transparent 51%);
            background-size: 1px 100%;
            background-position: center;
        }

        h1 {
            font-family: monospace;
            background-color: white;
            border: 1px solid deeppink;
            border-radius: 0.25rem;
            color: midnightblue;
            padding: 0.25em 0.5em;
            z-index: 100;
        }
```

```html
<body class="horver">
    <h1>width&ratio;height</h1>
</body>
```

I'm open to restructuring both the CSS and HTML as needed.

The idea is to then write a function that will return the width and height of the viewport dynamically/as it changes.

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Holy mackaroly- in production I'd just get an SVG and make it the background image of an element to act as my x-axis and y-axis, but I wanted to try it out this way.

Some of my code might get a little thick with css variables and lots of calculations, but the heart of it is this, instead of using psuedo elements for your axis, make them defined elements, and then use psuedo elements for the little "arrows" at the ends of your line.

To make an arrow I used a div element with a clip path to cut it in half. The border is used for the stroke thickness to match your line.

One thing is that you used `top: 50%` to place your axis halfway down, and this is partially correct, however if you ever have a thicker axis it would become immediately apparent, your line STARTS 50% down, so it's not truly centered.

To center the line, we need it to start `50%` minus half the thickness of your line. So I use `calc(50% - var(--stroke) / 2` to dynamically update the `top` value, this way you could update the stroke and have a still functioning project. Also, I feel that variables and calculations make things more clear than using "magic numbers".

You could also use `transform: translate` or just `translate` to offset the element by 50%, and sometimes this is more clear when reading, however I opted for the calculated method this time.

I consolidated lots of the css so shared stylings are written once, making things a little more DRY.

Another tricky part was after I made the psudeo elements acting as arrows rotate, I needed them to be moved away from the edge of the viewport to act as an arrow, so I had to calculate the value of the diagonal, subtract the value of the width, divide by 2, and that gave me the amount to move from the edge.

The JS in this example is surprisingly much easier to read and understand than the CSS. I hope the demo provides value to you- let me know if you have any questions!

```js
const w = document.querySelector(".w");
const h = document.querySelector(".h");

const updateSize = () => {
  w.innerText = window.innerWidth + "px";
  h.innerText = window.innerHeight + "px";
};

window.addEventListener("resize", updateSize);
window.addEventListener("load", updateSize);
```

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.horver {
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
  display: grid;
  place-content: center;
  position: relative;
}

.axis {
  position: absolute;
  --stroke: 1px;
  --bg-colors: 
    transparent 49%, 
    deeppink 49%, 
    deeppink 51%, 
    transparent 51%;
  background-image: linear-gradient(
    var(--direction, to right), 
    var(--bg-colors)
  );
  background-color: deeppink;
  background-position: center;
}

.x.axis {
  --direction: to right;
  top: calc(50% - var(--stroke) / 2);
  left: var(--stroke);
  width: calc(100% - 2 * var(--stroke));
  height: var(--stroke);
  background-size: 100% 1px;
}

.y.axis {
  --direction: to bottom;
  background-size: 1px 100%;
  height: calc(100% - 2 * var(--stroke));
  width: var(--stroke);
  top: var(--stroke);
  left: calc(50% - var(--stroke) / 2);
}

.axis::before, 
.axis::after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  --size: 20px;
  height: var(--size);
  width: var(--size);
  border: var(--stroke) solid deeppink;
  --edge-offset: calc(
    (sqrt(2) * var(--size)) / 2 
    - var(--size) / 2
    - var(--stroke)
  );
  --axis-offset: calc(
    -1 * var(--size) / 2 
    - var(--stroke) / 2
  );
  clip-path: polygon(
    0 0,
    100% 100%,
    0 100%
  );
}

.x.axis::before {
  left: var(--edge-offset);
  top: var(--axis-offset);
  rotate: 45deg;
}

.y.axis::before {
  top: var(--edge-offset);
  left: var(--axis-offset);
  rotate: 135deg;
}

.x.axis::after {
  right: var(--edge-offset);
  top: var(--axis-offset);
  rotate: -135deg;
}

.y.axis::after {
  bottom: var(--edge-offset);
  left: var(--axis-offset);
  rotate: -45deg;
}

h1 {
  font-family: monospace;
  background-color: white;
  border: 1px solid deeppink;
  border-radius: 0.25rem;
  color: midnightblue;
  padding: 0.25em 0.5em;
  z-index: 100;
}
```

```html
<div class="horver">
  <div class="x axis"></div>
  <div class="y axis"></div>
  <h1>
    <span class="w">width</span>&ratio;<span class="h">height</span>
  </h1>
</div>
```

EDIT: adding SVG option as response to comment

This is very similar, only I use an svg for the arrows so there are fewer calculations. I also got rid of the background-images because I don't think they were doing anything.

My svg is in a data uri format because I didn't want to link to a file- but you could just as easily have a file holding svg content and the same results. I just googled "svg arrow" to find one that fit my needs.

```js
const w = document.querySelector(".w");
const h = document.querySelector(".h");

const updateSize = () => {
    w.innerText = window.innerWidth + "px";
    h.innerText = window.innerHeight + "px";
};

window.addEventListener("resize", updateSize);
window.addEventListener("load", updateSize);
```

```css
* {
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

:root {
    --stroke: 5px;
}

body {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
}

.horver {
    width: 100dvw;
    height: 100dvh;
    display: grid;
    place-content: center;
    position: relative;
}

.axis {
    position: absolute;
    background-color: deeppink;
    background-position: center;
    top: 50%; left: 50%;
    translate: -50% -50%;
}

.x.axis {
    width: calc(100% - 2 * var(--stroke));
    height: var(--stroke);
}

.y.axis {
    height: calc(100% - 2 * var(--stroke));
    width: var(--stroke);
}

.axis::before,
.axis::after {
    content: "";
    --size: 75px;
    width: var(--size);
    height: var(--size);
    position: absolute;
    --axis-offset: calc(-1 * var(--size) / 2 + var(--stroke) / 2);
    --edge-offset: calc(-1 * var(--size) / 3);
    background-image: url("data:image/svg+xml,%3C%3Fxml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'%3F%3E%3C!-- Uploaded to: SVG Repo, www.svgrepo.com, Generator: SVG Repo Mixer Tools --%3E%3Csvg width='800px' height='800px' viewBox='0 0 24 24' fill='none' xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg'%3E%3Cpath d='M7.82054 20.7313C8.21107 21.1218 8.84423 21.1218 9.23476 20.7313L15.8792 14.0868C17.0505 12.9155 17.0508 11.0167 15.88 9.84497L9.3097 3.26958C8.91918 2.87905 8.28601 2.87905 7.89549 3.26958C7.50497 3.6601 7.50497 4.29327 7.89549 4.68379L14.4675 11.2558C14.8581 11.6464 14.8581 12.2795 14.4675 12.67L7.82054 19.317C7.43002 19.7076 7.43002 20.3407 7.82054 20.7313Z' fill='deeppink'/%3E%3C/svg%3E");
    background-position: center;
    background-size: cover;
}

.x.axis::before {
    top: var(--axis-offset); 
    left: var(--edge-offset);
    rotate: 180deg;
}

.y.axis::before {
    left: var(--axis-offset);
    top: var(--edge-offset);
    rotate: -90deg;
}

.x.axis::after {
    top: var(--axis-offset); 
    right: var(--edge-offset);
}

.y.axis::after {
    left: var(--axis-offset);
    bottom: var(--edge-offset);
    rotate: 90deg;
}

h1 {
    font-family: monospace;
    background-color: white;
    border: var(--stroke) solid deeppink;
    border-radius: 0.25rem;
    color: midnightblue;
    padding: 0.25em 0.5em;
    z-index: 100;
}
```

```html
<div class="horver">
  <div class="x axis"></div>
  <div class="y axis"></div>
  <h1>
    <span class="w">width</span>&ratio;<span class="h">height</span>
  </h1>
</div>
```

Comment: Holy moly…it's nearly perfect! I was going to write the functions but THANK YOU  for taking it on. And you're right, the JS is way easier than the CSS in this case.  Zooming in, I do see some (white) visual artifacts where the lines intersect with the arrowheads. Is that why you'd opt for an SVG solution, and if so ho might you approach it?

Comment: The reason there's artifacts is because this is an "illusion" of an arrow, while it's really a border which have special rendering properties, and though I preformed some calculations to make the positioning "Good enough" it's not absolutely perfect due to the way the square edge of shaft notches into a diagonal. I'm happy to show you an SVG solution as well in an hour or so :)

Comment: Thank you! I'd love to understand the SVG approach, especially as it may render more accurately. 

Comment: Thank you so much! Your explanations are really clear! As a designer, I am able to understand pretty much everything you've done here. Amazing. One question…will updating the --stroke value require that I re-encode the SVG data uri  to match the new width, e.g., if I wanted to go 2 px instead of 5 px?

Comment: I would personally just change the container `--size` that has the svg as a background, but then you end up with smaller arrow heads. If you needed a different arrow head style you could either create your own svg, or find another that fits your design. Lots of free resources out there, and [this is a great guide](https://svgpocketguide.com/) to writing them yourself or understanding them better :)

Comment: Thanks! I'm measuring the arrowhead strokes as about three pixels wider than the axes with XScope so I'll play with --size or pull in a new SVG. Looks like the  data uri code could use a lil' clean up too.

Thanks for the SVG reference. I'm definitely gonna devour that. SD! 